# Only call after_action for particular code paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a Rails controller that looks like the code below. An after_action is triggered after the external_click method. But I recently added another code path in case the referer is invalid and now I see that I do not want the after_action to be triggered for that path. Is there a way to prevent the after_action from being triggered in the else clause.

```
class ClicksController < ApplicationController
  after_action :track_click, only: :external_click

  def external_click
    if params[:url].present?
      if valid_referer?(request.referer)
        redirect_to processed_url
      else
        redirect_to product_show_path(Product.find(params[:product_id]))
      end
    else
      not_found
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a proc for the callback with the conditions.

`after_action :track_click, only: :external_click, if: -> { params[:url].present? }`

Comment: Thanks! In this case I did `after_action :track_click, only: :external_click, if: -> { valid_referer }` and created a separate method `def valid_referer
    @valid ||= valid_referer?(request.referer)
  end` so that the `valid_referer?` method wasn't called more than necessary.

Comment: According to official docs, this couldn't be working right, because `:only` has priority over `:if` in case they are used together, so the `:if` option will be ignored.
[Source](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.3.3/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html)